# How to render children as string in React, in reusable component

Tags: reactjs, components, children

I have created reusable component in React- reusableToolbar which I want to render some text inside, which is children.
How to render this component and pass children prop ?

This is how component looks like

```
   import React, { FC } from "react";
import { ReusableToolbarWrapper, StyledText } from "./styles";
import CloseIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Close";

export interface ReusableToolbarProps {
  childred: string;
}
export const ReusableToolbar: FC<ReusableToolbarProps> = (children) => {
  return (
    <ReusableToolbarWrapper>
      <CloseIcon
        style={{
          width: "14px",
          height: "14px",
          marginLeft: "20px",
          marginTop: "22px",
          marginBottom: "24px",
        }}
      />
      <StyledText>{children}</StyledText>
    </ReusableToolbarWrapper>
  );
};
```

And how should I render it here : ?

```
    import {Toolbar} from "./toolbar";
import {ReusableToolbar} from "./ReusableToolbar/ReusableToolbar.tsx";

function App() {
  return (
      <ReusableToolbar></ReusableToolbar>
      // <Toolbar/>
    
  );
}

export default App;
```

thanks

Comment: btw your interface childred instead of children

Comment: Too late now, but this should have been voted closed as "Not reproducible or was caused by a typo" since you've only a typo in referencing the `children` prop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

children is the prop that goes inside the tags like this

```
import {Toolbar} from "./toolbar";
import {ReusableToolbar} from "./ReusableToolbar/ReusableToolbar.tsx";

function App() {
  return (
      <ReusableToolbar>Hello world</ReusableToolbar>
      // <Toolbar/>
    
  );
}

export default App;
```

you can alternatively pass it as a regular prop like this

```
import {Toolbar} from "./toolbar";
import {ReusableToolbar} from "./ReusableToolbar/ReusableToolbar.tsx";

function App() {
  return (
      <ReusableToolbar children="Hello world" />
      // <Toolbar/>
    
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1):

First, in the `App` component you should replace `(children)` by `({children})` or `(props)` and then use `props.children`

```
export interface ReusableToolbarProps {
  children: string;
}
export const ReusableToolbar: FC<ReusableToolbarProps> = ({children}) => {
  return (
    <ReusableToolbarWrapper>
      ...
      <StyledText>{children}</StyledText>
    </ReusableToolbarWrapper>
  );
};
```

Then you can write the text to display inside the `<ReusableToolbar>` markup (everything inside the tag `<ReusableToolbar>` is passed to the component `children` property)

`<ReusableToolbar>Some text to display</ReusableToolbar>`